# R: How can I count the number of times specific words appear in a text file in R?

Tags: r, count, match

I have a large text file in R and a list of names (with first and last name; n=220). All those names are mentioned (most likely several times) in my text file. I am looking for the number of times each name is mentioned with both first and last name in my text file and would need to have a table with the name in one columns and the corresponding number of times the name is mentioned in the second column as a final product.

For example suppose my names are:
"David Smith" "Rachel Miller" "Carl Bekker" "Tiffany Bone" "Mike Miller"

And my text called "my_textfile" is:
"Hi my name is David Smith and I know Rachel Miller but I have no clue who Tiffany Bone is. Yet, I know someone called Rachel Bone. I also know that Rachel Miller knows both someone called Carl Bekker and Tiffany Bone. David Smith as a name is not very creative; but who cares? Maybe you, Rachel Miller?"

I would need to get something like this as a result:

Name                   Mentions
David Smith            2
Rachel Miller          3
Carl Bekker            1
Tiffany Bone           2
Mike Miller            0

I am sure this problem has a straight forward solution but I just don't seem to find it.

So far I have tried several functions like "sum(str_count(my.text, regex("\bNAME\b")))" but this didn't allow me to count multiple names at the same time and summarize the results in a table.
Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're nearly there! You just need to ['map'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_(higher-order_function)#:%7E:text=In%20many%20programming%20languages%2C%20map,when%20considered%20in%20functional%20form.) your counting function over the vector of names.

There are several functions in R base for performing tasks like this that differ slightly: `lapply`, `sapply`, `vapply` and friends. Have a look to see which best suits your use-case.

Here is your example using `sapply`

```r
nameVec <- c("David Smith", "Rachel Miller", "Carl Bekker", "Tiffany Bone", "Mike Miller")
text <- "Hi my name is David Smith and I know Rachel Miller but I have no clue who Tiffany Bone is. Yet, I know someone called Rachel Bone. I also know that Rachel Miller knows both someone called Carl Bekker and Tiffany Bone. David Smith as a name is not very creative; but who cares? Maybe you, Rachel Miller?"

# We map our counting function over the names list
counts <- sapply(nameVec, function(x) stringr::str_count(text, x))

counts
# >  David Smith Rachel Miller   Carl Bekker  Tiffany Bone   Mike Miller 
# >           2             3             1             2             0
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this is perfect and helps a lot!